# align columns in a Puppet ERB template

Tags: puppet

I have the following code in a Puppet ERB template:

```
<% if @server.class == Array -%>
<% @server.each do |server| -%>
server   <%= server %>
restrict <%= server %>  <%= @restrict[1] %>
<% end %>
<% end -%>
```

In the configuration file, since the IP addresses are not all the same number of characters, I am not getting an aligned output:

```
server   123.123.1.1
restrict 123.123.1.1  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
server   123.123.345.33
restrict 123.123.345.33  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
server   123.123.345.33
restrict 123.123.345.33  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
```

As can be seen, the mask line is not aligned with the other mask lines.

How can I align them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do anything you can do in Ruby code inside the ERB templates so this would work:

```
<% if @server.class == Array -%>
<% @server.each do |server| -%>
server   <%= "%-14s" % server %>
restrict <%= "%-14s" % server %>  <%= @restrict[1] %>
<% end %>
<% end -%>
```

i.e. you can format strings in Ruby similar to other languages. Ruby docs [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html).